# Are there any tricks to fill in a header in a WPF control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="com.Controls.AcceptedTransformation"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:com.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         >
<Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" Margin="3,3,3,3" Width="170">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="DarkOliveGreen" >
                <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBold">Column:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkColumnName" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBold">Var1</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbkTransformationList" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="0,3,0,0">Var2</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="0,0,5,0">Sample:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkSample" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

It it looks like this:

[image: Control picture]

Is there any easy way to get the green box to fill in the top, rounded corners and all?

Comment: Id first start with removing this `Margin="3,3,3,3"`

Comment: OMG.  I think I need to take a nap. Thanks.

Comment: Though that still isn't going to completely solve the problem.

Comment: No, you're right, the square goes up into the radius.  But it's a heck of a lot better than it was...

Comment: You can try putting a border with 0 thickness and a background colour with radius on the inner stackpannel, however it doubt it will be perfect. you could also lay the outside border over everything (since its quite thick), and would likely give the best results

Comment: Doesn't the border have to go around the elements in XAML?

Comment: There are ways to achieve it. i dont have wpf open, maybe some enterprising young jedi xamler could do up an example

Comment: have you looked at using a GroupBox and changing its template to your needs? Also perhaps what you are looking for is already developed in Material Theme as a GroupBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you will have once you remove margin is the content has still got squared off corners whilst your border doesn't.

You could clip the content but building a geometry to do so is complicated stuff. As a basic (software) engineering principle we should use the simplest thing does the job.

As a question orientated plus, this approach is also kind of a lateral thinking trick or "cheat".

To do this we can set the background of the border, which is already clipped.
Make the stuff on top of that transparent.
We can achieve that hard edged transition using a lineargradientbrush that has two stops in the same place.

Like this:

```
    <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="DarkOliveGreen" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="DarkOliveGreen" Offset=".33" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset=".33" />
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" Width="170">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBold">Column:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkColumnName" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBold">Var1</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbkTransformationList" Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="0,3,0,0">Var2</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Foreground="AntiqueWhite" Margin="0,0,5,0">Sample:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbkSample" Foreground="AntiqueWhite"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Stick that inside a grid in a window and set size to content... I get:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: I knew there just had to be a "trick" to this, super elegant and it looks GREAT. THANK YOU.